# Navigation bar background color is not coming in IE 9 & 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Here http://www.furniturestores.co.uk/, Navigation bar background color is not coming in IE 8 & 9. It is working fine for IE 10 & 11 and for all other browsers. I added this to header also

But still I am getting the same issue

Comment: "This is my site, fix it for me" is not the kind of question that we value around here. Actually, it's not even a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background` property instead of `background-color`.

Update this

```
.navbar {
  background: #f15a27;
  background: rgb(241,90,39);    // IE 7,6
  background: rgba(rgb(241,90,39, 1.0);  // IE 8
}


.header-container .top-links {
  background: #cd1971;
  background: rgb(205,25,113);    // IE 7,6
  background: rgba(rgb(205,25,113, 1.0);  // IE 8
}
```